# Parsing a list into a url string

Tags: python, parsing, url, lambda, url-parsing

I have a list of tags that I would like to add to a url string, separated by commas ('%2C'). How can I do this ? I was trying :

```
>>> tags_list
['tag1', ' tag2']
>>> parse_string = "http://www.google.pl/search?q=%s&restofurl" % (lambda x: "%s," %x for x in tags_list)
```

but received a generator :

```
>>> parse_string
'http://<generator object <genexpr> at 0x02751F58>'
```

Also do I need to change commas to `%2C`? I need it to feedpaarser to parse results. If yes - how can I insert those tags separated  by this special sign ?

---

EDIT:

```
parse_string = ""
for x in tags_list:
    parse_string += "%s," % x
```

but can I escape this `%2C` ? Also I'm pretty sure there is a shorter 'lambda' way :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
parse_string = ("http://www.google.pl/search?q=%s&restofurl" % 
               '%2C'.join(tag.strip() for tag in tags_list))
```

Results in:

```
>>> parse_string = ("http://www.google.pl/search?q=%s&restofurl" %
...                '%2C'.join(tag.strip() for tag in tags_list))
>>> parse_string
'http://www.google.pl/search?q=tag1%2Ctag2&restofurl'
```

Side note:
Going forward I think you want to use [`format()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) for string interpolation, e.g.:

```
>>> parse_string = "http://www.google.pl/search?q={0}&restofurl".format(
...                '%2C'.join(tag.strip() for tag in tags_list))
>>> parse_string
'http://www.google.pl/search?q=tag1%2Ctag2&restofurl'
```

Comment: I love those python one-liners :)

Comment: sometimes they're the only things getting me through the day

Answer (score 1):

`"%s"` is fine, but `urlparse.urlunparse` after `urllib.urlencode` is safer.

`str.join` is fine, but remember to check your tags for commas and number signs, or use `urllib.quote` on each one.

Comment: so what would be the final solution ?