# parsing url code into plain string in java

Tags: java

Hello guys I have difficulties in 
parsing url code for example:

`"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984422/parsing-a-list-into-a-url-string"`

to:

`"stackoverflow questions 3984422 parsing a list into url string"`

and also in some cases the links is shows like this :

> '" http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0024.html"'

by using the below code it shows the out put is :

"www.rgagnon.com javadetails java 0614.html"

any suggestion how to add more filter?

thanks for helping.

Comment: Which type or parsing do you need? The example is not sufficient.

Comment: any parse that will get the result into plain string without html tag

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
String url = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984422/parsing-a-list-into-a-url-string";
String plain = url.replaceAll("[/-]|http:|\\.com", " ").trim();
```

Comment: Nice, but how about `.com` ?!

Comment: thanks it helps a lot
but in some cases the links is like this :
"http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0614.html"
if I use your coding the output is :
www javadetails java 0614.html

Answer (score 1):

another option:

```
import java.net.*;

public class GetURLName
{
  public static void main(String args[]) {
  try{
      String urlAddress = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984422/parsing-a-list-into-a-url-string";
      URL url = new URL(urlAddress);
      System.out.print(url.getHost().replaceAll("[/.]|http:|www|com", " ").trim()+" "); 
      System.out.println(url.getPath().replaceAll("[/.-]|html", " ").trim());
      }
  catch (Exception e){
      System.out.println("Exception caught ="+e.getMessage());
  }
```

}
}

will give you this output

stackoverflow questions 3984422 parsing a list into a url string

Comment: thanks it helps a lot 

but in some cases the url code shown as :
"[http://rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0614.html]"
using your code the output is 

"www javadetails java 0614.html"
any suggestion 
thanks for helping
"

Comment: http://rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0614.html will turn into rgagnon javadetails java 0614.html , what output you wanted it to be?

Comment: i mean with http:// followed by www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-6.....html

and I want the output to be rgagnon javadetails java 0614 without html at the back

Comment: here is how System.out.print(url.getHost().replaceAll("[/.]|http:|www|com|html", " ").trim()+" ");  System.out.println(url.getPath().replaceAll("[/.-]|html", " ").trim()); , but i think you need to go to http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html and read about the replaceAll method... it will help you